# Is it a bad pattern: determine class of interface implementation

Tags: java, conventions

I have the interface

```java
interface Car {
  enum Type { MITSUBISHI, FORD }
  Car.Type getType();
```

And two of classes implementing the interface

```java
class Mitsubishi implements Car {
  @Override
  Car.Type getType() { return Car.Type.MITSUBISHI; }
}
class Ford implements Car {
  @Override
  Car.Type getType() { return Car.Type.FORD; }
}
```

And use it field like

```java
List<Car> cars = this.cars;
List<Mitsubishi> mitsubishiCars = cars.stream().filter(c -> c.getType().equals(Car.Type.MITSUBISHI)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Question, is this a bad pattern or not? If it is, then why?

Comment: What do you use `Car.Type` for? What is its purpose?

Comment: There's an item in *Effective Java*: "Prefer class hierarchies to tagged classes". You seem to be using both, though. The real question is, why do you need to know its "type"?

Comment: AFAIK it is not a bad pattern if you are not using `getType()` to differentiate items in a `List<Car>` for instance, but simply to specify a constant on the specified class.

Comment: @VincentC. it is a bad pattern to have to differentiate between subclasses in a list of superclass.

Comment: Hmmm @RyanSchaefer did I misunderstood the reason on why JDK 17 is implementing sealed classes?

Comment: Take a look at Liskov Substitution Principle

Comment: @Raildex if the developer is solely using `getType()`, to, for instance, enforce an `Object` to a certain type (during Jackson serialization/deserialization for instance), I am not sure it is violating LSP. Or did I misunderstood it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it seems like a bad pattern because the interface `Car` is not supposed to know who implements it, while containing this `enum Type` automatically acquires the knowledges of its potential implementations.

This said, it all depends how you think to use the `Car.Type`.

Most probably, you will want to use the enum values to determine specified actions to perform. For example:

```
//park the car depending on the type
switch (type) {
    case MITSUBISHI:
        //park in a certain way
    case FORD:
        //park in some other way
    //...
}
```

If that's the case, I see at least 2 further problems except for the interface knowing its implementations:

- Each time you have a new `Car`'s implementation, you'll need to enrich the enum `Type` inside the interface `Car`. It may be annoying
- When the values of `Type` become a lot, whatever flow structure (`switch`, `if` blocks etc.) will become huge and hard to maintain.

If that's the case, I'd rather create methods in the interface that handle the action according to the car's type. For example:

```
interface Car {
    void park();
}

class Mitsubishi implements Car {
    @Override
    public void park() {
        //way to park a Mitsubishi
    }
}
```

If instead you simply wanted to use the enum value just to print the type of car at some point (like in a log), then just add a `String getType()` method in the interface that returns the proper brand:

```
interface Car {
    String getType();
}

class Mitsubishi implements Car {
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "Mitsubishi";
    }
}
```

But overall, I wouldn't suggest such approach unless there is not a use you have in mind for `Car.Type` that you're not sharing (even though I really don't see how else you may want to use an enum except for the 2 cases I listed above).

### Post-edit

After seeing how you want to use the enum:

```
List<Car> cars = this.cars;
List<Mitsubishi> mitsubishiCars = cars.stream()
    .filter(c -> c.getType().equals(Car.Type.MITSUBISHI))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think you can just define your enum outside the interface, then  creating a `Type getType()` method in the interface and then using it like this:

```
 cars.stream()
     .filter(c -> c.getType() == Type.MITSUBISHI)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(assuming of course that `Mitsubishi` implementation will return `Type.MITSUBISHI` on `Type getType()`).